# Unable to save/update custom attributes

Tags: php, magento

When trying to save/update a product, facing the following issue

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '98763-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID

So I tried changing

```
$product->save();
```

to

```
$product->getResource()->save();
```

No doubt, it resolved the issue.

**But** now its not saving the custom attributes. How could I do that ?

Class for saving products :-

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php';


class Fuze_Class_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController {
    /**
     * Save product action
     */
    public function saveAction()
    {
        $storeId        = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
        $productId      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $isEdit         = (int)($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') != null);

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($data) {
            $this->_filterStockData($data['product']['stock_data']);

            $product = $this->_initProductSave();

            try {
               // $product->save();
                $product->getResource()->save();
                $productId = $product->getId();

                /**
                 * Do copying data to stores
                 */
                if (isset($data['copy_to_stores'])) {
                    foreach ($data['copy_to_stores'] as $storeTo=>$storeFrom) {
                        $newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->setStoreId($storeFrom)
                            ->load($productId)
                            ->setStoreId($storeTo)
                            ->save();
                    }
                }

                Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->applyAllRulesToProduct($productId);

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The product has been saved.'));
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage())
                    ->setProductData($data);
                $redirectBack = true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
                $redirectBack = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Saving product custom options (if this is what you meant with custom attributes?) happens in the `_beforeSave` of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`. You probably want to fix your issue at hand instead of finding your way around it.

Answer (score 0):

In case saving the custom attributes with the product model doesn't work, another approach would be to update the attributes with the product action resource model,

```
$storeId = 1;
$productId = 1;

$attributesData = array(
    'name' => 'New Product Name',
    'price' => 50.00
);

$productAction = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action');
$productAction->updateAttributes(array($productId), $attributes, $storeId);
```